# Spring secuirty core and cookie with grails

Tags: grails, cookies, spring-security

I am using Grails 2.1.2 with spring security core and I want it to use cookie so that user should not have to login for second time. I added the following to my Config.groovy

```
rememberMe.cookieName = "sptest_remember_me"
rememberMe.alwaysRemember=true
rememberMe.tokenValiditySeconds = 1209600
rememberMe.parameter = '_spring_security_remember_me'
rememberMe.key = "rem_me"
rememberMe.useSecureCookie=false
rememberMe.persistent=false
```

But the problem is I authenticate my user programatically using

```
springSecurityService.reauthenticate(username,password)
```

and this does not create a cookie for user. So how do I force spring security to create a cookie for all user no matter what.